# Edit \maketitle; print authors below each other

Tags: titles, author

I'm currently setting up a `.sty` file for an experimental protocol. In that style file, I'm editing the `\maketitle` command so that it prints my `titlepage` with all the information set in the various "variables" like `\author{}`.

That said, I wondered how I could print the different authors below each other. The default command is:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    \@author
\end{tabular}\par%
```

This results in an output like:

```
                   Author 1                      Author 2
```

(evenly spread over the linewidth)

What I want is

```
Author 1
Author 2
```

How can I achieve this?

#### Edit

I should point out, that I'm modifying the output of the authors based on the state of the self defined `\supervisor` variable. If a supervisor is set, the output should be

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Authors:}\\
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
            \@author
        \end{tabular}\par%
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Supervisor:} \\
        \@supervisor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Supervisor set]

In this case (where the supervisor is set), the names of the authors should be printed one below of the other.

---

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Experimental Protocol Title}
\author{Jon Doe \and Jane Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: The `titling` package might help.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty hack to get multiple rows in the tabular (which will probably break all kinds of stuff, I just don't know yet which):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Experimental Protocol Title}
\author{Jon Doe \and Jane Doe}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\and}{\\}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's _very_ dirty ;-) I think that the key is to modify the `\begin{tabular}`, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

Aesthetically, I think the  authors in the (centred) list should be left-aligned. This hack, with `xpatch` and `stackengine` does the trick. The authors in the list have to be separated with a semi-colon:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \usepackage{xpatch}

    \title{Experimental Protocol Title}
    \author{Jon Doe ; Jane Doe ; Tweedledum ; Tweedledee}
    \date{\today}

    \xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@author}{\setstackEOL{;}\Centerstack[l]{\@author}}{}{}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I don't want to have `\@maketitle` be redefined? I already modified that command. How could I only redefine `\@author` to your code?

Comment: Redefining `\@author` is beyond my capacities. Its function is to store the value of `\author`, and use it in macros, not to format it. But you can combine your modifications with this one.

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}` does the job

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!